# C program using mosquitto client library not working

Tags: c, client, mosquitto, broker

Can anyone please tell me why the below code is not working?

```
#include<mosquitto.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char id[4] = "4567";
    char *host = "localhost";
    int port = 61613;
    int keepalive = 60;
    const char *msg1 = "{ \"data\":\"Hello\" }";
    bool clean_session = false;
    const char *top = "data/test/abc";
    struct mosquitto *mosq = NULL;

    mosquitto_lib_init();

    mosq = mosquitto_new(id,clean_session,NULL);
    if(!mosq){
        printf("Not Created");
        return 1;
    }
    mosquitto_username_pw_set(mosq,"admin","password");

    printf("%s\n",mosquitto_strerror(mosquitto_connect(mosq,host,port,keepalive)));

    int err = mosquitto_publish(mosq,NULL,"admin",strlen(msg1),msg1,1,true);
    printf("Error number: %d",err);
    printf("\nerr description=%s\n", mosquitto_strerror(err));  


    mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using apollo broker, I compiled the code and its working without any errors but the published message is not reaching the broker

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the `mosquitto_loop*()` function, you need to use one of these to ensure that network traffic is processed. `mosquitto_publish()` is entirely asynchronous and does not guarantee delivery when it returns. If you want to be sure the message has been delivered, use the `on_publish` callback.

I would suggest something like this:

```
void on_publish(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int mid)
{
    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct mosquitto *mosq;

    mosq = mosquitto_new("id", true, NULL);
    mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mosq, on_publish);

    mosquitto_connect(mosq, "example.net", 1883);
    mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "topic, 11, "hello world", 0, false);
    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq, -1, 1);  // this calls mosquitto_loop() in a loop, it will exit once the client disconnects cleanly

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used all the callback functions(log_callback,connect_callback,publish_callback with mosquitto_loop()),  but for some reason, the program is only entering into the log_callback function and exiting the program without ever entering into connect_callback and publish_callback. If there was some error in publishing or connecting to the broker i think it would have shown in the err variable that I have used in the program. Am I doing something else wrong here?

Comment: You must use one of mosquitto_loop*(), otherwise you can't be sure of the data actually being sent. I've added an example.

Comment: I played around both your and mine code, looks like both our codes fail to work, if mosquitto_loop_forever() is replaced by mosquitto_loop(), I searched a lot to know the difference between them but did not find anything understandable..can u please tell me what exactly is happening in both the cases

Comment: mosquitto_loop _forever() keeps on calling mosquitto_loop(). If you only call mosquitto_loop() once, there is no guarantee that all data will have been sent over the network.

Comment: If the code I gave doesn't work for qos 0 then there's nothing I can do. In that case, on_publish() is called once the PUBLISH packet has been passed to the OS for sending. All the places I've seen that means the same as the packet being sent. If that isn't the case on your OS, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Oh okay, anyways can you explain me the flow of the program that you have written above. I mean in what order are the functions called and if this program is multithreaded or not. P.S. thank you so much for the help so far.